# How does kernel prompt Android that phone is connected in USB Mass Storage Mode?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb

Phone is running IceCream Sandwich. 
I would like to know how the kernel prompts the Android HAL/Framework that the phone is connected in USB Mass Storage Mode? 
When I say prompt I mean generate an `uevent`

> change@/devices/virtual/switch/usb_connected

This will lead to the usb connected message seen on the phone.

The issue I am currently facing:
Plug in the USB in the PC no reaction on phone or PC.
If you go to settings and disable/enable the USB debugging option, the phone is detected.

Obviously the fix that I am targeting should make the phone be detected on PC without the user having to play with the Settings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could this be a driver issue on the PC? Interesting problem...

Comment: Oh No! TronicZomB sorry to get your hopes down.. Its just another engineering build problem on the phone.

Comment: Thats the reason why I wanted to know what is the right location in the kernel/drivers that should be debugged. guess ill start with the whole usb subsystem...

Comment: Ok, it was a thought, I don't really know anything else it could be with my limited knowledge so far. Best of luck!

Comment: The Android device will advertise itself on the USB bus as a mass storage device.  Take a look at the code that handles user selection of USB behavior (charge only vs. mass storage vs. ...).

Comment: When you say android device do you mean the kernel or the userspace android? I am pretty sure the kernel will prompt android that the usb is connected in whatever mode and then android will advertise like you said.. Also which code are you referring to? the selection of USB is android settings apk?